# JavaScript, load component/call method only if needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am searching for a way to clean my HTML views from `script`-tags.

Example:

(A view with a script tag)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $jQuery().ready(function() {
        call.a.method();
    }
</script>
```

I would like to remove this script tag and put it into a class - this class should initizalize on the document ready event and execute the method which belongs to the called view.

How could I realize something like that? Is there some best practice?

Short version of my  intention:
1.) Remove script tags from html files and put this code into some methods/functions 
2.) Only call the method/function that belongs to a view if I call the view:
Example:
www.url.com/testview.html
Execute: obj.views.testview();

How could I realize something like a mapping and is it possible to identify the called file/view?

Comment: What framework are use using?

Answer (score 0):

must move it in to a script file :)

something.js

JS Code:

```
$jQuery().ready(function() {
        call.a.method();
    }
```

html code

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="scripts/something.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: I think you doesn't understand my question, or my description is very bad. I only want to execute the method that belongs to the called view - if i call something like url/view1.html i only want to execute obj.views.view1().

Comment: can you explain it better? cause what I understand from post is that: you want to get read of js code within HTML